# gdal_translate: error 1: Could not find an appropriate zoom level

Tags: gdal-translate

I'm trying to put a jpeg file (a map) into Sqlite mbtiles.

The command:

```
gdal_translate \
  -gcp 0 0 6.756394 45.192361 \ 
  -gcp 0 1080 6.756394 45.127057 \
  -gcp 1820 0 6.912606 45.192361 \
  -gcp 1820 1080 6.912606 45.127057 \
  etache.jpg etache.mbtiles
```

returns the following error:

```
Input file size is 1920, 1080
ERROR 1: Could not find an appropriate zoom level
```

Any clue?

Comment: MBTiles supports only EPSG:3857 coordinate system and the ground control points are perhaps presented in EPSG:4326.

Answer (score 2):

Try in two steps:

1. Insert ground control points into a virtual raster file.

   ```
   gdal_translate -of VRT \ 
     -gcp 0 0 6.756394 45.192361 \ 
     -gcp 0 1080 6.756394 45.127057 \ 
     -gcp 1820 0 6.912606 45.192361 \ 
     -gcp 1820 1080 6.912606 45.127057
     etache.jpg etache.vrt
   ```
2. Convert the result with gdalwarp

   ```
   gdalwarp \
      -of MBTiles \ 
      -s_srs epsg:4326 \
      -t_srs epsg:3857 \ 
      etache.vrt etache.mbtiles
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks user30184,
this works:

```
gdal_translate \
  -a_srs epsg:4326 \
  -gcp 0 0 6.756394 45.192361 \
  -gcp 0 1080 6.756394 45.127057 \
  -gcp 1820 0 6.912606 45.192361 \ 
  -gcp 1820 1080 6.912606 45.127057 \
  -co "TILE_FORMAT=JPEG" \ 
  etache.jpg \
  etache.mbtiles
```